# Which AWS products can use AWS S3 as a log sink?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I found that an S3 bucket can send it's own access logs to another SE bucket.

This is possible for Classic/Application/Network Load Balancers as well.

Are there any other AWS services that can use SE bucket as a log sink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, through [Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/), which can [take logs from a bunch of AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/aws-services-sending-logs.html) and then [export the data to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html).

At the moment, the list is:

- Amazon API Gateway
- Amazon Aurora MySQL
- Amazon Chime
- AWS CloudHSM
- AWS CloudTrail ([which in turn can watch lots of services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-aws-service-specific-topics.html))
- AWS CodeBuild
- Amazon Cognito
- Amazon Connect
- AWS DataSync
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Amazon Elastic Container Service
- Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service
- Amazon ElastiCache for Redis
- AWS Fargate
- AWS Glue
- AWS IoT
- AWS Lambda
- Amazon Macie
- Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka
- Amazon MQ
- AWS Network Firewall
- AWS OpsWorks
- Amazon Relational Database Service
- AWS Robomaker
- Amazon Route 53
- Amazon SageMaker
- Amazon Simple Notification Service
- AWS Step Functions
- AWS Storage Gateway
- Amazon VPC

CloudWatch can also take metrics from ~70 AWS services, or logs and metrics from your own EC2 instances and applications.